# strip HTML Tags with perl

Tags: html, perl, parsing, tags

Whats the easiest way to strip the HTML tags in perl. I am using a regular expression to parse HTML from a URL which works great but how can I strip the HTML tags off?

Here is how I am pulling my HTML

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;
my $now_string = localtime;

my $html = get("http://www.spc.noaa.gov/climo/reports/last3hours.html")
    or die "Could not fetch NWS page.";
$html =~ s/<script.*?<\'/script>/sg;
$html =~ s/<.+?>//sg;
$html =~ m{(Hail Reports.*)Wind Reports}s || die;
my @hail = $1;
```

Comment: The `<center>` cannot hold it is too late!

Comment: You probably should read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Try posting about the problem that you *actually* need a solution for instead of the technical detail that you *think* you need a solution for, and it's guaranteed you'll get a better, simpler, answer.

Comment: You realize you make no sense. I need to strip the HTML tags off. Thats not technical and I dont "think" thats my problem I know thats my problem

Comment: No. If you weren't approaching your problem from entirely the wrong direction you wouldn't have any need to "strip HTML tags". Presumably you're trying to get some information from the page. That's data extraction / scraping. Scraping doesn't involve "stripping" HTML unless you're doing it entirely wrong from the beginning. So again, what is your *actual* goal?

Comment: I am assuming you are also the one to down my question one point? I wish I could knock you down some points because you dont deserve any with the way you treat everyone on here

Comment: I didn't, so I guess that makes **yet another** bad decision you've made based on an incorrect assumption. If you'd like me to prove that I didn't downvote your question, I can do so by downvoting it now.

Comment: My goal is to pull a small section of text from the middle of a page. It lies between two words that are always there and nowhere else on the page. So since I am still learning perl I figured regular expressions would work well until I learn to do it with tokens or something. It does work well for a quick fix. Even the books I have been reading say you can use regular expressions, but they usually dont work well because of the changing pages and most people learn to do it differently later. Which is exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: @hobbs I apologize for being rude, but you really are helping me no more than you say I am explaining myself. I did say lower in the page what my intentions were and that I knew regular expressions are not good to use with HTML parsing. You explained nothing just tore down the one answer that did what I needed it to and did not give me any incite to a better way just that it was "shitty" as you put it. Again I apologize for being rude to you last night.

Comment: hobbs is right, that you are likely approaching the problem with the wrong solution in mind, and you would do better to step back and explain what you really want to achieve.  The problem is not "strip tags from a html page", but rather "extract content from the middle of a page". That's a much more solution-agnostic way of stating the question, and you might be surprised at the solutions you find. hobbs was immediately suspicious (as well he should be) because attempting to parse HTML with a regexp is a mistake 99.999% of the time.

Comment: The main thing here is that I just ask for something. I know as I have said that using regular expressions is not the best way to do this but it works for what I am doing now until I learn to do it another way. Since someone answered my question clearly my question has a solution whether or not you guys like it.

Comment: +1 shinjuo for sympathy.  Questions should not be down voted without warrant.

Comment: You say "it works for what I am doing now until I learn to do it another way."  Hobbs is trying to teach you to do it another way.

Comment: Then teach me. There was no teaching at all

Comment: Give a man a fish, he's fed for a day. Teach him how to fish, and he's fed for life. hobbs was trying to teach you how to fish. For that, he needed to know the purpose behind stripping out your HTML tags. Which is why he asked, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## An attempt to answer your misguided question

### Problems

---

It's a bad habit to get into regex'ing out HTML because there are so many rules and ways to get around them, that may eventually open your code up to hacking techniques.  While you might  have a legitimate need for something simple now, it is very easy to reuse code and forget why it was a bad idea to reuse it, especially when you don't add comments like `# This code is NOT secure and should not be used to parse HTML anywhere else!!!` or `# Christina Alguilera writes songs based on this code!!!`

#### Example of differences in HTML that require lots of regex rules:

```
<div>...</div>
<div style="blah">
<div style="background:url(../div)">
<div style=".." class='noticesinglequote'>
```

The list goes on and that's only for well-formed HTML.  Some other examples of problems include:

1. HTML elements closed improperly (eg `<div><span></div></span>`) or not at all
2. Spelling errors (eg `<dvi>..</div>`)
3. HTML designed with the intention to break your script
4. Other issues: comments, whitespaces, charsets, etc

### Solution

---

You may have accepted an answer, but you should look at [XML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/%7Emsergeant/XML-Parser-2.36/Parser.pm) and [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/%7Epetek/HTML-Tree-3.23/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder.pm).

Rather than stripping out parts of the HTML Document, you are probably more interested in drilling down to the part of the document you want (eg everything in `<body>` or a certain `div` inside of it), which is why you most likely want something that one of the above modules provide.  Not to mention, parsers can be used to do their best at removing all HTML elements and returning only text/CData.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I am currently reading the Perl & LWP book to learn to write with tokens. The only reason I accepted the solution is because I wanted a program that just pulls a small amount of data between the words hail damage and storm damage. My simple program accomplishes that. Now that it is logging the data I need every ten minutes I am going to rewrite it using tokens.

Comment: All I need is just the words between Hail damage and storm damage and the regex works for that. It does not do everything I want it to do at the moment, but logging the information from the site was the most important and this was just a simple work around until I learn more. As for reusing it, I am working on upgrading it now. I will not reuse it.

Comment: **@shinjuo:** The NOAA page you have listed provides a dynamically generated CSV file for their data.  It'd be better to just retrieve data using that file, that way no parsing is even needed.  Otherwise, it seems the information you want is contained in a table, so again, all you have to do is traverse the HTML tree to the data that you need.

Comment: The reason I am pulling it off the page and not the file is because If a hail size is larger than 2.0 I want it to email me the information listed. They update that every 10 minutes

Comment: **@shinjuo:** The hail size is in the CSV.  If it's larger than 2.0, it can easily email all the information in the CSV.

Comment: But wouldnt that mean I would have to download the file every 10 minutes?

Comment: You either need to download the csv or the html page every 10 minutes, one's no better than the other.  The difference is that one (csv) has less data and is easier to pull information from

Comment: Is there an easy way to download files from the internet? I have not read that far in my books

Comment: I think it's the same exact code with LWP::Simple, instead of retrieving a `.html` file, you're just getting `.csv`, both are text-based files.

Comment: Sometimes users need to clean up HTML before *any* XML parser can even parse it without choking.

Comment: @DanJacobson That's good practice, but if it's not simple to do via standard regex and treating it like any other string, then you probably want to XML parser to wade through it anyhow to reduce it to the core parts youre after, that or have more control over the source text you're feeding to the parser.  Beyond that, you may need to express your particular problem.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned, don't use regular expressions for this.  There are simply too many exceptions.

One CPAN module which can help is [HTML::Strip](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Strip/):

```
use HTML::Strip;

my $hs         = HTML::Strip->new();
my $clean_text = $hs->parse( $raw_html );
$hs->eof;
```

It's worth learning what's available on the CPAN and making use of it. It will save you a lot of work in the long run.

Comment: Yeah I have been getting on there and looking around. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the [HTML::Restrict](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aRestrict) module which allows you to strip away or restrict the HTML tags allowed. A minimal example that strips away all HTML tags:

```
use HTML::Restrict;

my $hr = HTML::Restrict->new();
my $processed = $hr->process('<b>i am bold</b>'); # returns 'i am bold'
```

I would recommend to stay away from HTML::Strip because [it breaks utf8 encoding](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=42834).

Comment: The `HTML::Restrict` is probably the best there is, but it doesn't work with Perl 5.8.x -- which is still found in some production environments.

Answer (score 0):

there is also a nice Perl module  HTML::Scrubber.

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 use warnings; 
 use strict;
 use HTML::Scrubber;
 my $file = shift or die "need a file $!\n";

 my $html;
 open (FH,"< $file");
 read( FH, $html, -s FH );
 close FH;
 #print "$html\n";

  my $scrubber = HTML::Scrubber->new;
  $scrubber->default(1); ## default to allow HTML

   #$scrubber->script(0); ## no script
   #$scrubber->style(0); ## no style
   # OR
   $scrubber->deny(qw[script style]);

   my $clean_html = $scrubber->scrub($html);

  open (OH, '>', $file.'.scrubbed.html');
  print OH $clean_html;
  close OH;
  exit;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to remove HTML tags:

```
s/<script.*?<\/script>//sg
s/<.+?>//sg
```

This will (most of the time) remove script tags and their contents, and all other HTML tags. You could also probably remove everything before the `<body>` tag safely with regex.

For *anything* more complex than that, though, regular expressions are *not* a suitable tool, and you really need to parse the HTML with an actual HTML parser and then manipulate that to remove the tags.

Comment: I know that you should use tokens more than regular expressions but with what I need to do regular expressions works well.

Comment: I am still very knew to perl and intend on rewriting my program the correct way but I just want to get it going for now and then work on the other way after it is done. I know people dont like that idea and most say just do it right the first time, but i just want to get it going quickly and will then adjust it correctly

Comment: @Anon where would I put that code you gave me? I put a snippet of my code in my question for you to see.

Comment: You want to match the fetched HTML against the two regexes - after fetching the page, you can put `$html =~ s/<script.*?</script>//sg`, and similarly for the second one.

Comment: Anon, `s/<script.*?</script>//sg` needs a `\\` before the `/` in `</script>`.

Comment: I have updated my code to what you gave me which works very well. While we are is there an HTML parser made that I should use or is it better to write your own? I have only read the learning perl book and I am now on intermediate perl.

Comment: @Kinopiko: Indeed it does. Thanks. @shinjuo: When it comes to Perl, if you ever find yourself asking "Is there an {X} already made", the answer is probably "Yes, and you'll find it on CPAN". The base module is known as HTML::Parser, and there are several other modules derived from/based on that which you may find useful.