# Download files with Perl

Tags: html, perl, download

I have updated my code to look like this. When I run it though it says it cannot find the specified link. Also what is a good way to test that it is indeed connecting to the page?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use LWP;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new;

$browser->credentials(
    'Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS):80',
    'datawww2.wxc.com',
    '************' => '*************'
);

my $response = $browser->get(
'http://datawww2.wxc.com/kml/echo/MESH_Max_180min/'
);

$mech->follow_link( n => 8);
```

---

(Original Post)

What is the best way to download small files with Perl?

I looked on CPAN and found lwp-download, but it seems to only download from the link. I have a page with links that change every thirty minutes with the date and time in the name so they are never the same. Is there a built-in function I can use? Everyone on Google keeps saying to use Wget, but I was kind of wanting to stick with Perl if possible just to help me learn it better while I program with it.

Also there is a user name and password to log into the site. I know how to access the site using Perl still, but I thought that might change what I can use to download with.

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: you should have started a new question, rather than modify the old.  the two questions are different, this is in regards to authentication, which i answered in the comment below.  You don't need the Apache...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in a comment in your other question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176842/strip-html-tags-with-perl/3183200#3183200)

You can use the same method to retrieve `.csv` files as `.html`, or any other text-based file for the matter.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use LWP::Simple;

my $csv = get("http://www.spc.noaa.gov/climo/reports/last3hours_hail.csv")
           or die "Could not fetch NWS CSV page.";
```

To login, you may need to use [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm) to fill out the webform (look at `$mech->get()`, `$mech->submit_form()`, and `$mech->follow_link()`)

Comment: This is actually for something a little different than that page. On this page the links are updated every thirty minutes and the names are always different since they are a time and date. So I cant just put in the link name

Comment: you'll want to use `WWW::Mechanize` then.  `$mech->follow_link` can follow the n'th link, or a link with specified text, or a link that matches a regex.

Comment: Will mechanize work with a popup login? http://datawww2.wxc.com/kml/echo/MESH_Max_180min/

Comment: You may have to do something like: `http://username:password@ datawww2.wxc.com/kml/echo/MESH_Max_180min`, otherwise you might have to capture the cookie.  I don't know how you came across that link, so I couldn't tell you.

Comment: This is a link to a weather reports site. I was given the link user name and password. So I always just go straight to the link

Comment: Try the link with the url in the format as shown above, feeding the username/password beforehand (`username:password@`).  Otherwise you have to pass the authentication somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you need to fetch the page, parse it to get the URL, and then download the file.

Personally, I'd use `HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath`, write a quick XPath expression to go straight to the correct href attribute node, and then plug that into LWP.

```
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new;
$tree->parse({put page content here});
foreach($tree->findnodes({put xpath expression here}){
    {download the file}
}
```