# How to read and store a spreadsheet from a URL

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Download files with Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191950/download-files-with-perl)

I am new to Perl and I need to access a url to read and store the excel file  present at the url i.e. url is of type www.abc.com/xyz.xls. Can you please provide a simple example to do it? I need it urgently at my work.

Comment: This is (more or less) in the FAQ: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq9.html#How-do-I-fetch-an-HTML-file%3f — There is no difference in the technique for getting any other kind of file over HTTP.

Comment: I second the reference to the perl FAQ, particularly the second example using `getstore()`.  Just do this:    `use LWP::Simple qw(getstore);
    getstore( "http://www.example.com/foo.xls", "foo.xls" );`

Comment: Similar question, but storing binary file after fetching is addressed here and not there.

Answer (score 4):

To download a file, use LWP::Simple:

```
use LWP::Simple qw(getstore);
getstore( "http://www.example.com/foo.xls", "foo.xls" );
```

That is literally all you need to download the file.  **Update:** Having trouble getting it working?  Here is how you can add some error handling:

```
use strict;                     #standard good practice
use warnings;                   #ditto
use LWP::Simple qw(getstore);
use HTTP::Status;               #Get the HTTP error messages

my $status = getstore( "http://www.example.com/foo.xls", "foo.xls" );
print status_message($status);
```

If you need to access the file's contents within Perl, this is a bit more complicated.  Look into [`Spreadsheet::ParseExcel`](http://search.cpan.org/~kwitknr/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel-0.2603/ParseExcel.pm) or [`Win32::OLE`](http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-OLE-0.1709/lib/Win32/OLE.pm).

Comment: Please elaborate.  What sort of error/problem are you having?  Also, what is the exact code you are using?

Comment: The updated code above with error handling might help you see where you are going wrong.