# writing shell script

Tags: shell

I want to write a shell script that will read a file from standard input, remove all  string and empty line character, and write the output to the standard output. the file look like this:

```
#some lines that do not contain <html> in here
<html>a<html>
<tr><html>b</html></tr>
#some lines that do not contain <html> in here
<html>c</html>
```

So, the output file should contain:

```
#some lines that do not contain <html> in here
a
<tr>b</html></tr>
#some lines that do not contain <html> in here
c</html>
```

I try to write this shell script:

```
read INPUT #read file from std input
tr -d '[:blank:]'
grep "<html>" | sed -r 's/<html>//g'
echo $INPUT
```

however this script isn't working at all. any idea? thx

Comment: You might want to try this in Perl (or something other than a certain shell,) if possible: [check out the answer(s) on this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176842/strip-html-tags-with-perl)

Comment: @summea I can't. I have to use #!/usr/bin/bash

Comment: should the comments be preserved?

Comment: I guess I don't understand why you have multiple `<html></html>` pairs in one document, as well...

Comment: I don't know it either. it just some random file that my teacher give to us

Comment: @summea this is his first time he teach us about linux scripting. and he told us to do this homework using grep-sed :(

Comment: This can only end badly... but I hope it works out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
    #ignore comments
    [[ "$line" = "\#" ]] && continue
    #ignore empty lines
    [[ $line =~ ^$ ]] && continue
    echo ${line//\<html\>/}
done < $1
```

Output:

```
$ ./replace.sh input
#some lines that do not contain in here
a
<tr>b</html></tr>
#some lines that do not contain in here
c</html>
```

Pure sed:

```
sed -e :a -e '/^[^#]/N; s/<html>//; ta' input | sed '/^$/d'
```

Comment: what [[ "$line" = "\#" ]] mean? and I can't only use grep and sed

Comment: see comments in source above

Comment: so the first sed will remove <html>, but what the second sed do?

Comment: second one deletes empty lines

Answer (score 1):

Awk can do it easily:

```
awk '/./ {gsub("<html>","");print}' INPUTFILE
```

First it operates on every line with at least one character (so empty lines are discarded), and it replaces "`<html>`" globally with an empty string on the line, then prints it.

Comment: OP needs comments to be preserved

Comment: I can only use grep and sed. but what is /./ mean? is it mean the current directory?

Comment: @HannaGabby - `/./` is a regular expression that means one character [any]